# Get first row of each group in access2010

Tags: sql, ms-access

There are multiple way to get first row from each group, but none of my idea is working with access2010.

Do you have a solution to get first row in access2010 ?

Or

```
ID Name Age
1 Name1 3
2 Name2 4
3 Name1 2
4 Name2 5
```

It should get the top row in each group (name column) so the output would be

```
1 Name1 3
2 Name2 4
```

Comment: is your id column is identity column?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that still uses a sub query, but only once, instead of on each record.

```
SELECT T1.* 
FROM   mytable AS T1 
WHERE  T1.id IN (SELECT First(T2.id) 
                 FROM   mytable T2 
                 GROUP  BY T2.name)
```

Comment: This is known as the Top N in Group pattern. You will probably need to assign a table name alias within the subquery in order to refer to it twice without Access throwing an error.

Comment: The query worked for me as is. But since I like table name alias' to make it more readable, I have edited it.

Comment: +1: I upvoted your original answer because it worked for me, too. With all of the variations in SQL dialects I wish that more people would actually *test* their answers ***in the actual context*** (as you apparently did) instead of **(1)** guessing, or **(2)** offering a solution for a *different* SQL dialect while trying to be "helpful".

Comment: Thanks. I see # **(2)** quite a bit. I think that probably confuses things more than it helps.

Comment: +1 Yah, you probably only NEED the alias if you are referencing the smae field(s) in both the inner and outer layers, but it can help readability as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table t1 where ID in
(sel min(ID) from table where t1.name=name);
```

Comment: I shouldn't use subquery , that is a condition here. it became a tough one for me.

Comment: strange..but there doesn't seem any good solution without using subq